# How to get root document from sub collection documento in firestore?

Tags: ios, google-cloud-firestore

I have my collection "photos", each document inside this collection have a sub collection orders. I have a order doing an collection group query. How can i then have the photo in witch this order is containded??

Answer (score 1):

You can get from the `DocumentSnapshot` in the subcollection to its parent document with:

```
document.reference.parent.parent
```

The first `.parent` gets you the subcollection this document is from, and the second `.parent` gets you the document that this subcollection is under.

Answer (score 0):

Your query will have a bunch of DocumentSnapshot objects in it.  Each one of those has a [reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentSnapshot#reference) property that contains the full path of the document.  You can use its [parent](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentReference#parent) property to find the CollectionReference where that document lives, and you can keep walking up the path with the parent property on each DocumentReference and CollectionReference, as far up as you need.